# LineHeight in EGOTextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, core-text, css

Im employing [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) to do rich text editing. But the `lineHeight` of the `EGOTextView` appears a little smaller than in the `UITextView`, which are set the same font.
I have tried to set the `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight` and `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineHeight` in the default attribute, but it is not a good solution as I need to insert image which has to modify the `lineHeight`. Any help will be appreciated:)

[image][image]

**EGOTextView.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"UITextView", @"EGOTextView", nil]];
segment.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.navigationItem.titleView = segment;
[segment release];

if (_textView==nil) {
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
    self.textView = textView;
    [textView release];
}

if (_egoTextView==nil) {
    EGOTextView *view = [[EGOTextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    view.delegate = (id<EGOTextViewDelegate>)self;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    self.egoTextView = view;
    self.egoTextView.delegate = self;
    [view release];  
    [self.egoTextView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
}
[segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing` on the `CTParagraphStyleSetting` for the `NSAttributedString` to the number of points you would like to separate lines by. Alternatively, you could also specify a line height multiple using `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineHeightMultiple`, for increasing line height by a factor.

Here's a quick example:

```
CGFloat lineSpacing = 0.f; // spacing, in points
CGFloat lineHeightMultiple = 0.f; // line height multiple

CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphStyles[2] = {
    {.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing, .valueSize = sizeof(CGFloat), .value = (const void *)&lineSpacing},
    {.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineHeightMultiple, .valueSize = sizeof(CGFloat), .value = (const void *)&lineHeightMultiple}
};

CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphStyles, 10);
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:(__bridge id)paragraphStyle
                            forKey:(NSString *)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName];
CFRelease(paragraphStyle);
```